# Mocking propertysource for integration test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, integration-testing, spring-boot-test

I have a configuration class as

```
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
@PropertySource(value = { "file:/config/appconfig.properties" })
public class ExternalProperties {
// varibles which get initize with @Value
}
```

which reads value from a file. But When I am trying to write integration test cases so at the time of initalization its failed as the appconfig.properties in present in the test env. And I am getting below error

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /config/appconfig.properties (No such file or directory)
> at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)

How to initizae the test enviroment in this case. what is the way we can point the PropertySouce to some other temp location?

Answer (score 0):

You can first configure `@PropertySource` 's `ignoreResourceNotFound` as true such that the test can still continue executing in case of failure to load the  properties file :

```java
@PropertySource(value = { "file:/config/appconfig.properties" }, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class ExternalProperties {

}
```

Then use `@TestPropertySource` to configure a properties file just for that test class such as :

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class FooTest {

}
```